# ApacheBeam Python ReadAllFromText in streaming dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read pubsub message which is generated from GCS whenever a file is created or updated in gcs path , message looks something like below

```
{
    "kind": "storage#object",
    "id": "somesomething",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/somesomething.csv",
    "name": "folder/folder/acco_data_big.csv",
    "bucket": "<bucket name>",
    "generation": "1611592382820095",
    "metageneration": "1",
    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
    "timeCreated": "2021-01-25T16:33:02.905Z",
    "updated": "2021-01-25T16:33:02.905Z",
    "storageClass": "STANDARD",
    "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2021-01-25T16:33:02.905Z",
    "size": "10",
    "md5Hash": "GgnS0V05XvRfygHDq0ysQg==",
    "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/asdda-access-ddf-1/o/sub%2Fstationary_data.csv?generation=5543&alt=media",
    "crc32c": "uuSlBw==",
    "etag": "CP/dgLzBt+4CEAE="
  }
```

Based on this message I extract file path from name and bucket tag, and then read the file using `beam.io.ReadAllFromText()` , then pass to next Pardo class for further processing , finally writing in Bigquery using  `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery`.
This works in DirectRunner but in Dataflow last step is silent, not even giving any errors.

Comment: What version of Python SDK did you use and what does the code of beam.io.WriteToBigQuery Transform look like?

Comment: If this still concerns you, probably reaching out to Dataflow support is the most efficient way to debug it. The answer might be hiding in the cloud logs or their internal backend logs.